# LWJGL 3.0.0 does not produce a window after upgrading from 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, macos, maven, lwjgl

It seem like the LWJGL 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is available anymore, so I had to go for LWJGL 3.0.0. However, to me it looks like the Mac binaries are broken.

I have downloaded the natives using the following script, that have been working in the past. The only line that has changed is:

```
 <lwjgl.version>3.0.0SNAPSHOT</lwjgl.version> -> <lwjgl.version>3.0.0</lwjgl.version>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Meltdown</groupId>
<artifactId>Bitflip</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Bitflip</name>

<properties>
    <lwjgl.version>3.0.0</lwjgl.version>
    <!--<lwjgl.version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</lwjgl.version>-->
    <swt.version>4.5.1</swt.version>
    <joml.version>1.8.0</joml.version>
    <class>game.SpaceGame</class>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>mac</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>Mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
                <artifactId>lwjgl-platform</artifactId>
                <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
                <classifier>natives-osx</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
                <version>${swt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>res</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.lwjgl.demo.${class}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <finalName>lwjgl3-demos</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>swt-repo</id>
        <url>http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joml</groupId>
        <artifactId>joml</artifactId>
        <version>${joml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

To be sure I made a test running the example code from LWJGL's web page: [link to src](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide)

```
package org.gooeybits.meltdown.alt;

import org.lwjgl.Version;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class Test {

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        try {
            init();
            loop();

            // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
            glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        } finally {
            // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
            glfwTerminate();
            glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if (!glfwInit())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure our window
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        int WIDTH = 300;
        int HEIGHT = 300;

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
        });

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        // Center our window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
        );

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }
}
```

I have also set the following VM options:

```
-XstartOnFirstThread 
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

The following native binaries was downloaded (Maven):

```
libglfw.dylib
libjemalloc.dylib
liblwjgl.dylib
libopenal.dylib
```

When compiling and running the project, it executes normally with no warnings/errors or exceptions. The only thing missing is the window. I have tried both fullscreen and stand alone. But nothing.

My question is can you see anything weird that I'm doing or have you had something similar happening?

**Update:** This call never returns.

```
 window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I uninstalled CUDA drivers and the JDK. Rebooted and installed Java 8 build 91, instead of build 92.

And it worked. However I still do not know if it was something wrong with my CUDA installation, or if it was the JDK.

But if anyone have similar problems, please give it a try.

```
java -cp .:./jar/*:./native -Djava.library.path=./native/ -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true -XstartOnFirstThread HelloWorld
Hello LWJGL 3.0.0 build 90!
[LWJGL] Version: 3.0.0 build 90
[LWJGL]      OS: Mac OS X v10.11.5
[LWJGL]     JRE: 1.8.0_91 x86_64
[LWJGL]     JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM v25.91-b14 by Oracle Corporation
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl
[LWJGL]     Loaded from java.library.path: ./native/liblwjgl.dylib
[LWJGL] ThreadLocalUtil state: UnsafeState
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil accessor: MemoryAccessorUnsafe
[LWJGL] Loading library: glfw
[LWJGL]     Loaded from java.library.path: ./native/libglfw.dylib
[LWJGL] Loading library: objc
[LWJGL]     Loaded from java.library.path: ./native/libobjc.dylib
[LWJGL] Loading library: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
[LWJGL]     Success
```